# dispaly all fields dynamically in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp

I am creating application in CakePHP. 
Now I am giving functionality to end user so he/she can add their own custom field in any table. 
now user can able to create field properly and also able to input and edit.

For this I used `$this->Form->inputs();` Now when I use view or index page that field in not showing. As writing proper field name is not good idea. Any body have idea how to display all other custom fields.
I don't want to use

```
<?php echo h($student['Student']['id']); ?>
```

I want it will show directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP have special feature `Scaffolding` which will create all the add/edit/index pages dynamically.

Please have a look at http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Scaffolding.html